# ValueError: unsupported format character ';' (0x3b) at index 946 HTML email with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas, string, html-email

I'm trying to send an email in HTML format with pandas dataframe

I've converted pandas dataframe to html code using `.to_html(index = False)`

While passing converted dataframe to HTML code using `%s` is throwing an error as

```
ValueError: unsupported format character ';' (0x3b) at index 894
```

When I use `.format()` for passing the parameter it is throwing

```
KeyError: '\npadding' error
```

Here is my code

```
html_body = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
th,td{
padding: 10px;
}
.dataframe{
border:1px;
width: 80%;
padding: 25px;
margin: auto;
margin-top:30px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dee2e6;
border: 1px solid black;
}

table thead tr {
background-color: #dee2e6;
}
td{
background-color: white;

}

table, th, td{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2 style="text-align: center;"> We found anomalies in following record/s </h2>

{dataframe}



</body>
</html>'''.format(dataframe=html_df)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the `ValueError` comes from the fact you have an unescaped `%` character in your html text (`width = 80%;`). If you replace it by a double `%%` it should work (`width: 80%%;`) as in the following example:

```
html_body = '''<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
th,td{
padding: 10px;
}
.dataframe{
border:1px;
width: 80%%;
padding: 25px;
margin: auto;
margin-top:30px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: #dee2e6;
border: 1px solid black;
}

table thead tr {
background-color: #dee2e6;
}
td{
background-color: white;

}

table, th, td{
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<h2 style="text-align: center;"> We found anomalies in following record/s </h2>

%(dataframe)s



</body>
</html>'''  % {"dataframe":"bla"}
```